# HighCharts 3.0.0 Animation

Tags: highcharts

I upgraded to HighCharts version 3.0.0 today and am having some issues with animation.  The web application I am working on is built for IE 9.  I am getting no animation in IE but when running chrome the animation still renders for my application.  I can however view highcharts demos in IE 9 on the official site with full animation.

```
        chartVar = document.createElement('div');
        chartVar.setAttribute('id', 'container');
        chartVar.style.width = '400px';
        chartVar.style.height = '200px';
        document.getElementById('quad0').appendChild(chartVar);
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },

                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
                }]
            });
        });
```

Comment: Do you use any .ASP wrappers?

Comment: Do your local testing with the same version that the demos are displayed. `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`

Comment: I do not use any asp wrappers.  As for the version, I obtained it by sending a request to the page recommended by Eduardo, copied all of the text and saved it over my copy of highcharts.js.  I am working in visual studio if that has any effect.